# XMSerializer with Polymer elements exposes shadow dom

Tags: dom, polymer-1.0

Using XMLSerializer on a DOM that contains polymer elements, exposes the shadow dom of those elements (using polymer 1.0 and and chrome 54). Not sure what to make of it, possibly it is to be expected, but perhaps someone has a solution to not having the shadow DOM exposed without performing serialization "by hand".

As an example, please see https://gist.github.com/jcage2010/5a92686317bef63d711bac74bc6d5944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look you're running with native shadow DOM. (Note the 'style-scope' attributes, for example. To turn on native shadow DOM, see:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings

I would be surprised if this was the case with native shadow DOM, but I'd expect to see all of the nodes in shady DOM.

Comment: very helpful, had totally missed this. Setting window.Polymer = {
      dom: 'shadow'} allows shadow dom to remain hidden. Many thanks!